# OFFSET sql and EF Skip no compatibility in IIS 7.5 with win server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, rest, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

In my local computer with Windows 11, visual studio 2022, I create a project API REST and I have a request to the database, something like this

```
result = await appDb.table
                        .Skip(data.Index)
                        .Where(something here)
                        .Take(data.NumberToTake)
                        .ToListAsync();
```

it works fine in my local computer, but when I publish the code to my IIS 7.5, windows server 2008 R2, gives me this error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

if I change my code and erase the skip command it works well. I understand that the problem is the version but I don't know how to get the .net core version that is using the IIS 7.5 (some time ago I install a bundle to allow the run of asp.net Core projects, but don't know which version is running actually) or maybe is something else.

Edit:
this is the bundle I install to run .net core:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.4-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Any ideas of what can I do?

Comment: The only thing that matters is the version of SQL Server you're using - and your database's compatibility level. You need to be running SQL Server 2012 or later to use `OFFSET`: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2362/overview-of-offset-and-fetch-feature-of-sql-server-2012/ and your compatibility level needs to be `110` or higher.

Comment: asp.net core only supports Windows 7 or later or Windows Server 2012 R2 or later.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Yes that's true, I had to enable TLS 1.2 to make it work: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/topic/actualizar-para-habilitar-tls-1-1-y-tls-1-2-como-protocolos-seguros-predeterminados-en-winhttp-en-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end what I do was:

```
Result = await appDb.Table
                    .Where(...)
                    //.Skip(data.Index)
                    //.Take(data.NumberToTake)
                    .ToListAsync();

Result = Result.Skip(data.Index).Take(data.NumberToTake).ToList();
```

Is inefficient but until I find a better way, this works for now.